# JSF2: NullpointerException at custom composite component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, myfaces, composite-component

I've been trying to create an own component to "replace" the Richfaces spacer, which is no longer available in Richfaces 4.

I have found this link for the actual implementation: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SpacerImplementationForJSF2OrRichFaces4

I tried to register the new taglib:

richext.taglib.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

<namespace>http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/richext</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>spacer</tag-name>
        <source>../richext/spacer.xhtml</source>
    </tag>
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/richext.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

changed the spacer.xhtml a little bit to:

```
<composite:implementation>

    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{cc.attrs.height > 0}">
        <br/>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:graphicImage value="../img/spacer.gif"
                    width="#{cc.attrs.width}px"
                    height="#{cc.attrs.height}px"/>
</composite:implementation>
```

I added

```
xmlns:richext="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/richext"
```

to the pages where I want to use the spacer.

My Files:
WebContent/WEB-INF/richext.taglib.xml

WebContent/richext/spacer.xhtml

WebContent/img/spacer.gif

Now, when accessing a page where I use the spacer (other pages work fine) I get a NullpointerException in the browser, not in the server log.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.composite.CompositeComponentDefinitionTagHandler.apply(CompositeComponentDefinitionTagHandler.java:113)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:57)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:48)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:394)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:448)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:390)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.UserTagHandler.apply(UserTagHandler.java:138)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:51)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:59)
at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:53)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.java:294)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:54)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:51)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:57)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:51)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:48)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:179)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.buildView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:417)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:78)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:763)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:454)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:919)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1016)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:895)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1659)
```

Where did I go wrong? Am I missing something?

My Server is a Websphere 8.0.0.2 if that's important.

Thanks in advance

Comment: missing the </facelet-taglib> but that's not my error :)

Comment: and using MyFaces 2.0.15. so now i finally got it

Comment: What do you mean with "i finally got it"? Is your problem solved?

Comment: No, I mean I finally provided all the information others may be looking for. I'm sorry to confuse you

Comment: Does nobody have a solution for this? hard to believe I'm the only one with this problem

Comment: You don't need that `richext.taglib.xml` file and `web.xml` entry at all. Just put the composite component in `/resources/richext` folder, exactly as explained in the answer you found. The incorrect taglib might have caused MyFaces to choke like that.

Comment: Okay, I reposted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need that `richext.taglib.xml` file and that `web.xml` entry at all. Just put the composite component in `/resources/richext` folder, exactly as explained in the answer you found. Your concrete problem is caused because you attempted to register a composite component as a tag file (which are two entirely separate concepts). The incorrect taglib file might have caused MyFaces to choke like that.

#### See also:

- [Composite component info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info)
- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen/6822269#6822269)